# Miranda's book pag. 60

Tags: general-topology, riemann-surfaces

The author’s dealing with the connected sum of two topological spaces. He defines the map $\pi: X \sqcup Y \mapsto Z$ and endows $Z$ with the quotient topology. He also says that the natural inclusions of $X$ and $Y$ in $Z$ are continuous and if $A \subset X$, then $i(A)$ is open in $Z$.
I’ ve done this proof: let $W \subset Z$ an open set, so $\pi^{-1}(W)$ is open in $X \sqcup Y$ by quotient topology. We have $i^{-1}(W)=X \cap \pi^{-1}(W)$, so the inclusion is continuous.
For the second part I want to find some equality like the previous one, but I can’t.  Can you help me?

Comment: What is Z? It's definitely important.

Comment: Z is the set that contains the singletons $\{x\}$ ($x \in X\setminus U$), $\{y\}$ ($y \in Y \setminus V$) and the doubletons $\{u,\phi(u)\}$ where $u \in U$.

Comment: @federico: And what are constraints on $U$ and $φ$?

Comment: $U \subset X$ and $V \subset Y$ are open and $\phi:U \mapsto V$ is a homeomorphism.